# Resize an image for retina display

Tags: css, retina

I'm trying to find a way to resize an image for retina display, without it being a background image or using different images.

My plan is to use 800x600 px images, and for normal displays simply down sample this to 400x300, but for retina keep it at 800x600 but at double the pixel density, i.e it gives the appearance of showing 400x300 but it has twice the pixel density.

Is there a way to do this in CSS?

The closest I can get is something like this to find the retina ratio:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

But then how to make the images display at twice the pixel density, effectively making it half the size on the retina?

Comment: _"for normal displays simply down sample this to 400x300, but for retina keep it at 800x600 but at double the pixel density, i.e it gives the appearance of showing 400x300"_ - that doesn't need any media queries, just `width:400px; height:300px;` - _because_ CSS Pixels and Device Pixels are different things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will make some use of this Retina.js by imulus - seems to have wide variety of tools useful for dealing with retina-only media queries.

Here's the link: http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/

Still, it's not a way of dealing in CSS, you'd have to give the JavaScript a little bit of love here.